# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'accounts.User' that has not been installed

Tags: python, django

i'm getting these error in my code:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'accounts.User' that has not been installed
```

Why am i getting this Error??
I can't understand why it doesn't work
i'm added AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User' to settings

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from .managers import UserManager
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionRequiredMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('email', 'full_name')  # just for createsuperuser

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

managers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, phone_number, email, full_name, password):
        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError('user most have phone number')
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('user most have email')
        if not full_name:
            raise ValueError('user most have full name')

        user = self.model(phone_number=phone_number, email=self.normalize_email(email), full_name=full_name)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone_number, email, full_name, password):
        user = self.create_user(phone_number, email, full_name, password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'phone_number', 'full_name')

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password1'] and cd['password2'] and cd['password1'] != cd['password2']:
            raise ValidationError('The password are not match')
        return cd['password2']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password2'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(
        help_text="you can change your password using <a href='\"../password/\"' >this form </a>")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'phone_number', 'full_name', 'password', 'last_login')
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


# Register your models here.


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    readonly_fields = ('last_login',)
    list_display = ('email', 'phone_number', 'full_name', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        ('Main', {'fields': ('email', 'phone_number', 'full_name', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions',
         {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_admin', 'is_superuser', 'last_login', 'groups', 'user_permissions')})
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'phone_number', 'full_name', 'password1', 'password2')}),

    )

    search_fields = ('email', 'full_name')
    ordering = ('full_name',)


admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Everything I did didn't work, does anyone have any ideas???
How can I solve this problem?
I had typed this code before, but it didn't have the same error
How to solve this there is any idea .. I am stuck on it .. django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'user.CustomUser' that has not been installed . Though i have added AUTH_USER_MODEL in my settings.py . But it is not working

Comment: add `'accounts'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: i'm added this but its not working

Answer (score 0):

I am 99% sure you forgot to migrate your model.
To do so add you app to installed apps:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'accounts',
]
```

Then open terminal run `python manage.py makemigrations` in your manage.py directory.
Next apply migrations `python manage.py migrate`